# Keter not picking up new bundle

Tags: haskell, deployment, yesod, keter

I'm trying to deploy a Yesod app using Keter. I previously added a `*.keter` bundle to `/opt/keter/incoming`, but because I built the file on a different system it failed to start. I've since fixed this problem by building my app on the server itself.

However, now when a new `*.keter` bundle is added to `/opt/keter/incoming/`, nothing happens. `/opt/keter/log/keter/current.log` doesn't have any log messages since I had the first failed deploy. I see several instances of Keter running when I run `ps aux | grep kete[r]`, so it does look to be running.

I copied the `*.keter` bundle I made to a temporary directory, where I gunzip/untarred it. After doing so, I was able to run the binary directly, so I think that's ok.

Edit: I notice that inside the `temp` director that Keter uses, there is only a binary there (no static assets or anything). When I try to run this binary it fails with "Segmentation fault".

Trying to run `keter /opt/keter/etc/keter-config.yaml` is proving really useful—am working through some issues and I think I'm down to just a postgres authentication failure. Will report back in a bit.

Comment: There are problems starting a new yesod instance if there are database changes and the migration last too much, or the migration fails. Possible solution: run it in cmd-line with same environment target to complete or resolve db migrations, then kill the task and retry copying keter to the income folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've worked through all the issues. Roughly, the steps were:

1. `tail -f` the app and keter `current.log` files for information
2. Run keter manually `keter /opt/keter/etc/keter-config.yaml`

   - This would bring up issues like not having the certificate.pem file (I didn't need this because I'm not using https yet)
3. Use the app's logfile to work out issues like database connection errors.

   - I didn't end up using Keter to handle this—I just set up postgres manually.

This is sort of an abridged answer—can't quite remember all the things I needed to do. However, the key here was to run keter manually to bubble up any errors that were occurring.